# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/core/ResourceMethod when tried to migrate JBoss 6.3 to WildFly 10

Tags: java, wildfly, resteasy, jboss6.x, wildfly-10

I need some help by you.
I'm trying to migrate my application in JBoss 6.3 to WildFly 10, but when I start the wildFly I have the follow error:

***org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/Backoffice/api/soa/financeiro/spo/1.0": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/core/ResourceMethod***

I'm using the resteasy version 3.0.19.Final and tried use others older and newer...but always this error occurred.

This is my dependencies in pom.xml

```
   <!-- core library -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <!-- multipart/form-data and multipart/mixed support -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

My JBoss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/Backoffice/${context.root}/${api.version}</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            
            <!--module name="org.apache.commons.codec" /-->
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
            <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
            
            <!-- <module name="br.com.tm.seguradora.soa.thread" /> -->
            <!--module name="net.sf.json" /-->
            <!-- <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true"/> -->
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My module.xml for resteasy-jaxrs

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="async-http-servlet-3.0-3.0.19.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.19.Final.jar"/>
        <!--<resource-root path="resteasy-client-3.0.19.Final.jar"/>-->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.codec" />
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" optional="true" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <!--<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-validator-provider-11" optional="true" services="export" export="true"/>-->
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And my module.xml for resteasy-multipart-provider:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.19.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.mail.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.james.mime4j"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Somebody knows what could happening please? When I start **Jboss eap 6.3** Its works fine without errors.

Thanks for all!!

Comment: Can you remove the <scope>provided</scope> and try?

Comment: Yes...I already did it, but the server continuous with the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're editing the RESTEasy module?

Comment: No @JamesR.Perkins, I just edited it to make some tests, but it not work. I rollback the archive module to original now.